# how to fetch backgrid with two parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, backbone.js, backgrid

I am using `backgrid.js` for table that I want to fetch backgrid with two parameter.

Now here my code I am trying with one parameter. But I don't know how to send two parameter.

```
 territories.fetch({ data: { status: 1 }, processData: true, reset: true });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to send multiple options to the data option of ajax. According to [Backbone collection fetch documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch),

> jQuery.ajax options can also be passed directly as fetch options, so to fetch a specific page of a paginated collection: `Documents.fetch({data: {page: 3}})`

In your case, maybe you can do something like:

```
territories.fetch({ 
    data: { 
        status: 1, 
        anotherParam: "another param value" // or whatever you want it to be
    }, 
    processData: true, 
    reset: true 
});
```

We can pass as many parameters as we want, just like [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). ( Read about `data` option )

Comment: Although I try those code It is only send one parameter 
here my code 
territories.fetch({ 
    data: { 
        status: 1, 
        user_id: 556
    }, 
    processData: true, 
    reset: true 
});

Comment: Oh I m a bad guy. I make wrong file edited. Now I got it . Thanks @Cyclone

Comment: Glad it helped. A piece of advice @Nay, if you can spend sometime in reading the [backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/), it would really help to understand the framework, it has many interesting things that one can utilize :-)